# Custom ant task to automate android apk generation

Tags: android, ant

I want to automate my android apk generation process. The app fetches data from server, I have two servers, one is for testing which contains dummy data, and the other one for actual release which contains real data. URL of those servers are mentioned within `strings.xml` file.

Now I need a custom ant task for generating two different apks, one pointing to the test server and the other one pointing to the real server.

My problem is, I don't know how to write `strings.xml` file from ant script so that it can change the URLs accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the replace task in ant. Something like this:

```
<replace file="res/values/strings.xml" token="@@@" value="http://myUrl"/>
```